# Delete specific words from path php

Tags: php, path, dns, words

How to delete specific words From Paths?

i have path:

```
/home/domains/www.mydomain.com/cdn/img/users/135/1341143/big_a514e41ba2187ffda494714e5a4e521f.jpg
```

but i need

```
/www.mydomain.com/cdn/img/users/135/1341143/big_a514e41ba2187ffda494714e5a4e521f.jpg
```

How to make it?

Comment: Do you get this as a string in php or where does this data come from?

Comment: yes i take it into string in variable: $sPathSaveTo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use simple `str_replace()`

```
$string ='/home/domains/www.mydomain.com/cdn/img/users/135/1341143/big_a514e41ba2187ffda494714e5a4e521f.jpg';

   $newString = str_rplace('/home/domains','',$string);

   echo $newString;
```

Comment: I totally forgot about this feature, THANKS